# View controller transition error

Tags: ios, swift, segue, multipeer-connectivity

I am receiving this error after dismissing a multipeer connectivity window:

```
"Warning: Attempt to present < AudioWaves.ViewControllerJoin: 0x176cf2d0> on < AudioWaves.ViewController: 0x17594de0>  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"
```

Here is my code below,

```
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(
    browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController!)  {
        // Called when the browser view controller is dismissed (ie the Done
        // button was tapped)
        let ViewControllerjoin:ViewControllerJoin = ViewControllerJoin()

        self.presentViewController(ViewControllerjoin, animated: true, completion: nil)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

If I put the dismiss before the presenting of the new view controller the browser dismisses however the app simply brings to a blank black screen with no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain your two calls like this:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
    self.presentViewController(ViewControllerjoin, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

This way chains first the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and then the `presentViewController`, this prevent your hierarchy from strange behavior

**This helped the asker to verify that his ViewController indeed is the black screen:** Try changing the background color of the ViewControllerJoin to blue for example and trying again, once I saw that the default backgroundColor caused a black screen in a ViewController (this seems to help the

Comment: Doing this makes the first view not disappear at all and impossible to leave

Comment: this works exactly the same as the other one where the view is dismissed then lead to a black screen

Comment: please give more detail of your view controllers and the order they are appearing

Comment: I think maybe there's something wrong with your main ViewController, from where you present the `MCBrowserViewController` and from where you want to present the `ViewControllerJoin`, if not, then try changing the background color of the `ViewControllerJoin` to blue for example and trying again, once I saw that the default backgroundColor caused a black screen in a ViewController

Comment: Yeah I set the default background color to red in the viewdidload, and instead of reaching a black screen I reach a red screen, however also when I add a button to my original view controller that takes to the ViewControllerJoin the background color is red but it shows the rest of the view controller, I am just at a loss at what is even going on.

Comment: now that you know that your ViewController is there, you could embed it in a Navigation controller to add cancel controls and maybe correct the default color to be white and do the things you are pretending to do with it

Comment: Is there any way to do this while making the Navigation controller not shown, as I personally like the design of my app without it, or to atleast change attributes of the navigation controller as I cannot select it.